# React Native Document picker How to make file selection one by one?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-document-picker

There is an "add file" button. Each time we click on the button, a new element is created. In the element, we select the file that we want to upload. (to use the two buttons 'choose file' and 'delete') We select the file and after the element should be updated, and in the middle the name of the selected file should appear (button "choose file" and "delete" does not disappear). When writing with the 'Delete' command, the file is reset and you can select it again. Follow the "add file" procedure with a new element with the same functionality.

The problem I faced:

Every time I select a file, its name is only displayed when the next item is added. (not updating the selected file) Every time a new item is added, the file name is duplicated instead of showing an empty item. (the name of the file selected in the first element is displayed in each new element). When adding a new file, instead of getting an element with a new name of the file being added, the lines with the file name are duplicated one under the other (however, they have different file names, as they should)

Question: How to implement adding a file to different elements?

What am I doing :

1. There is a button that adds a new item and allows the user to select a file:
2. Implementation of the file selection button:

```
const FilesView = () => {
      const viewFileElement = multipleFile;
      console.log(viewFileElement);
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
        style={MapStyle.SelectFileButton}
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={selectFile}
        >
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',color:'blue'}}>Select File</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
      <View style={MapStyle.inputText2} key="{multipleFile}"><Text>{multipleFile.name}</Text></View>
      </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={MapStyle.DeleteButtons} onPress={() => { deleteItems(); deleteFile();}}>
                    <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Delete</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

```
const addItems = () => {
    const arr = [...views];
    arr.push(<FilesView />);

    setViews(arr);
  };

  const deleteItems = () => {
    const arr = [...views];
    arr.push();

    setViews(arr);
  };

const deleteFile = async () => {
        const del = [...multipleFile];
        del.pop();
        setMultipleFile(del);
      };
```

3. Selecting a file and writing it to an array:

```
const selectFile = async () => {
    try {
        let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
      //const res = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
      //  type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
    //  });
      
      //console.log('res : ' + JSON.stringify(result));
     
      //const newFile = [...multipleFile];
      //newFile.push(result);
      setMultipleFile(result);
    } catch (err) {
      setMultipleFile(null);
      if (DocumentPicker.DocumentResult({type: 'cancel'})) {
        alert('Canceled');
      } else {
        alert('Unknown Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
```